# htaccess redirection to particular folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have installed word press in the public html folder of my hosting. I have put my  old codeigniter site files into "oldsite\codeigniter". But i am unable to access this code igniter website always getting page not found error from word press

Sample URL : example.com/oldsite/codeigniter

How can i redirect to sub folder if the URL contains "oldsite" or oldsite/codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldsite/codeigniter/(.*)$ example.com/oldsite/codeigniter/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

codeigniter htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.gif|.jpg|.png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule  codeigniter/home$ 
example.com/oldsite/codeigniter[L,R=301]
```

Comment: There should already be some .htaccess inside oldsite/codeigniter.

Comment: yes i have a htaccess file in the codeigniter folder and the code is

Comment: Then you shouldn't need the first .htaccess, because the codeigniter .htaccess takes care of everything. Only remove the last line.

Comment: i have removed the redirection rule from wordpress htaccess and also removed the last line from codeigniter htaccess. but facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but is a bit too long.

To reiterate the initial setup: Wordpress is installed in the document root, `public_html`. And there's an old CodeIgniter website, which is installed in `public_html/oldsite/codeigniter`.

There should be just two .htaccess files necessary, one for Wordpress and one for CodeIgniter. Both are taken from their respective websites, `https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess` and `https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html`

```
# /public_html/.htaccess
# Wordpress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

```
# /public_html/oldsite/codeigniter
# CodeIgniter
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

---

If this fails for some reason, it might be that Apache is confused because of the relative path `index.php`. *If* this is the reason, you can fix it by using an absolute path, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /oldsite/codeigniter/index.php/$1 [L]
```

or add a [`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive

```
RewriteBase /oldsite/codeigniter
```